# How to store input from a loop to an array in assembly(mips). How to store the integers I read in arrA?

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, mips, store

I create a 2d array with nested loops and I dont understand how to store the read integers in the arrA.When i try to print one of the array's elements its does print only a(2,1) and a(2,2). I would appreciate your help.

```
 #
 # $t0 = Pointer to current beginning of row
 # $t1 = Row counter and index
 # $t2 = Column counter and index
 # $t3 = Pointer to current address to store data 
 # $t4 = Value to be stored in each array element
 #
 #

 .data

   arrA:       .space 32
   arrB:       .space 32
   arrC:       .space 32  



  bracA:      .asciiz "a("
  bracB:      .asciiz "b("
  bracC:      .asciiz "c("
  comma:      .asciiz "," 
  endBrac:    .asciiz ")= "
  nextLine:   .asciiz "\n"

     .text
  main:

  la $t0, arrA                #load base of Array a
  la $a1, arrB                #load base of Array b
  la $a2, arrC                #load base of Array c


  li $s0, 1                   #set i
  li $s1, 1                   #set j
  li $s2, 1                   #set k
  li $s7, 1                   #counter
  move $t1,$0


rloop:     move $t2,$0
           move $t3,$t0 




cloop:     move $s0, $t1
           move $s1, $t2 

           li $v0, 4
           la $a0, bracA
           syscall

           li   $v0, 1  
           addi $s0, $s0,1               #prepare to print integer
           move $a0, $s0                 #print i
           syscall

           li   $v0, 4
           la   $a0, comma
           syscall

           li   $v0, 1
           addi $s1, $s1,1
           move $a0, $s1                 #print j
           syscall

           li   $v0, 4     
           la   $a0, endBrac
           syscall
           li   $v0, 4     
           la   $a0, nextLine
           syscall

           li $v0, 5
           syscall
           move $s3, $v0

           sw $s3, 0($t3)
          addi $t2,$t2,1 
          beq $t2,2,nxtrow
          addi $t3,$t3,4 
          j cloop

 nxtrow: addi $t1,$t1,1
         beq $t1,2, print
         add $t0, $t0, 8
         j rloop


  print:li $v0,1
        lw $a0, 0($t0)
        syscall
  end: li $v0, 10
       syscall
```

Comment: There's no such thing as 2D array in assembly. You have 1D memory (address = 1 dimension). To have [MxN] array you have to figure out some "mapping" function fm(m,n) -> address, which has to be usually 1:1 mapped (i.e. it has also inverse function). Usually "address = n\*M+m" formula is used, and M\*N memory elements are allocated for such array.  .... about your code... you have 3 indices there (i, j, k), and it's not clear what that code should actually do, some example input/output would help.

Comment: Try your code in debugger and watch memory window, how your values are stored (the `sw $v0, arrA` is probably overwriting the same spot, so you have only last input stored instead of some array?). This may give you lot of ideas, how to improve (for example try 1 dimensional array first). Also your code has very bad style (indentation, excessive empty lines, short non-descriptive labels (what is doing "loop" except looping?), etc), so it is very difficult to read. Don't save time while writing the source, invest into restyling/proper naming, as you will read your source much more, than write it

Comment: Yes i know theres is not a 2d array in assembly. I understand what you are trying to say and thanks for the advice in styling . I ll keep it in mind.

Comment: Now I see (by very very quick look on source) only one value printed, from current `t0` (which is first element of actual row == probably a(2,1)?). But the storing of input into memory looks like it may actually work, did you try in debugger with memory window opened watching arrA array, and relevant register values? The printing is not that hard, once you have memory structures correct and input filling them up. At the moment I would be curious about your `tX` register usage, actually I wonder if those are preserved by `syscall`, I don't think so, can't find definitive yes/no answer right now

Comment: I would suggest to follow more locality/argument patterns in register usage, like don't load `arrB` address, if you are not using it yet, `arrA` is enough, etc... the storage address can be probably just in single register all the time (`t3` vs `t0`), i/j/k look to be redundantly duplicated by `t2`, etc.. try to simplify/reuse values where reasonable, to minimize register usage. (locality = comment + init + usage of particular register spans across minimal possible amount of lines, comments on top are long time forgotten in the middle of code). And I think `rloop: ... move $t3,$t0` is not good